# For loop iterator with methods in java

Tags: java

I am try to execute one simple for loop with iteration done by method. Its return value is not assigned

```
    public class DefaultC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        for(i= 10;i<=50; i=method(i)){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    static int method(int i){
        return i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: read about post increment operator. It doesn't return what you think it does.

Comment: do a return `i + 1`

Comment: i = method(i), it return each time value incremented by one. but it didnt assigned.why?

Comment: @Prashant by i++ it works, but why i = method(i) cant?

Comment: @karthick Please read more about the scope of the variable and then about post and pre-increment operator.

Answer (score 5):

`++i` increments **and then returns `i`**.

`i++` returns `i` **and then increments it**.

Answer (score 3):

```
static int method(int i){
        return i++;
    }
```

This method is doing **post-increment**, which means it will return the value of `i` as it is which is being passed as the method argument, after that it increments the value of `i` which is now not useful at all since the scope of the variable i is only up to this method.

Try doing pre-increment instead.

```
return ++i;
```

**EDIT:** As per OP's comment

> @Prashant by i++ it works, but why i = method(i) cant?

```
for(i= 10;i<=50; i++){ <-- Here post increment happens 
  System.out.println(i); <-- At this point value is already being incremented so you can utilize it.
}
```

Where as

```
for(i= 10;i<=50; i=method(i)){ <-- Here post increment happens inside method and the value it returns is still `10` not `11` 
      System.out.println(i); <-- At this point value is same as the previous loop
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `i++` works but `increment(i)` doesn't is because of the difference in the variable you are incrementing.

- `i++` is incrementing a local variable, so you see the changes to its value;
- `increment(i)` is copying `i` to a new variable, which happens also to be named `i`, and increments *that*, and *after* taking its value for the return statement.

  The variable local to the loop is left unchanged by the `++`, just as `int j = i; j++;` doesn't change the value of `i`.

In Java, method parameters​ are [always passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/3788176).

But it is also important to note that even if Java did pass method parameters by reference, there is still a semantic difference between `i++` and `i = i++` (which is like the `i = increment(i)` case). The other answer have already covered why `i = i++` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i++ returns the value of i and later it do increment.
What you need to do is, to use ++i;

Given Example shows how,

```
public class DefaultC {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 1;
    for(i= 10;i<=50; i=method(i)){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

 static int method(int i){
    return ++i;
 }
}
```

Here ++i will do increment first and returns later